# ModSecurity audit log rule limit

Tags: logging, audit, mod-security

Is there a way to limit the amount of rules which appear in every log entry with ModSecurity?

```
--173fad2e-A--
[27/Apr/2016:17:15:25 +0530] VyCmVMCoAwUAAAohwTgAAAAA 127.0.0.1 33330 127.0.0.1 80

[...]

--173fad2e-H--
Message: Warning. Pattern match "^5\\d{2}$" at RESPONSE_STATUS. [file "/etc/modsecurity/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_50_outbound.conf"] [line "53"] [id "970901"] [rev "2"] [msg "The application is not available"] [data "Matched Data: 503 found within RESPONSE_STATUS: 503"] [severity "ERROR"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.9"] [maturity "9"] [accuracy "9"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-13"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A6"] [tag "PCI/6.5.6"]
Message: Warning. Pattern match "^(?i:0|allow)$" at RESPONSE_HEADERS. [file "/etc/modsecurity/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_55_application_defects.conf"] [line "151"] [id "981405"] [msg "AppDefect: X-FRAME-OPTIONS Response Header is Missing or not set to Deny."] [data "X-FRAME-OPTIONS: "] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-15"] [tag "MISCONFIGURATION"] [tag "http://websecuritytool.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Checks#http-header-x-frame-options"]
Message: Warning. Operator GE matched 4 at TX:outbound_anomaly_score. [file "/etc/modsecurity/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_60_correlation.conf"] [line "40"] [id "981205"] [msg "Outbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (score 4): The application is not available"]
[...]

--173fad2e-Z--
```

That's an example of an audit log entry, I would like to configure it so it only shows a "Message" in the log trailer per log entry, instead of (in the example) 3.

Is it possible to configure that?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why you would want to do this?

The reason it's showing three is because this request has triggered three different rules.

Often ModSecurity will block for the first failed rule and so you won't see this. The fact the did **not** block the request (and therefore prevent the rest of the rules firing) suggests one of two things:

1. Either you are running in DetectionOnly mode. In this mode it's especially helpful to see all rules otherwise you fix one rule only to discover another and so on.
2. You are running anomaly detection mode, which runs all the rules, totals up the errors, and then blocks if the number of errors is greater than a set limit. This allows one or more minor rules (which may otherwise have lots of false positives and therefore block legitimate traffic), to pass if the sum total of the anomaly score is under the limit. Again in this mode you need to see all the rules that failed.

So, to me, ModSecurity is doing exactly what it should here and not sure why you think it should only show one rule?

Comment: It's not about what >it< should do, but more about what >I< want it to do. To be more specific I'm parsing the log entries, and it's pretty impossible at this moment to detect all the rules ( H ) and the header ( A ) all at once in the same log.
If it can be configured so it shows for each rule a log entry, then that would be the ideal behaviour for me to match on some regex and categorize the threat (each of those 3 in the example).

Comment: Well how can you categorise the threat without knowing all the rules it fails for? AFAIK you cannot do want >you< want it to do but feel free to raise a request (or better yet do the code changes!) on git but personally can't see there being much call for this from others. To be honest the audit logs aren't great for parsing - much better to use the error logs where the failed rules are on one line per rule. You could even write a custom rule at beginning of phase 5 to list the headers you want on this line as well as the error message if needs be.